# How to display a customizable menu using Main page and Sub page in wordpress?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I want to display my menu in this format in my project

**Main Page 1

  Sub-Page1

  Sub-Page2

Main Page 2**

**Problem**

I have wriiten the wp_nav_menu to display menu pages in the menu but when I try to make this type of customized menu I get confused to display the menu like this type.

Please someone help to me to display this menu.

Comment: r  u in search of something like this plugin does..http://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-custom-menu/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<?php
    $pages = get_pages( array(
                'sort_order' => 'ASC',
                'sort_column' => 'post_title',
                'parent' => 0 )
                );
    ?>

    <?php
        if ($post->post_parent)
            //I am a subpage
            $id = $post->post_parent;
        else
            //I am a page
            $id = $post->ID;

        $subpages = get_pages(array("child_of"=>$id));
    ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($pages as $page):?>
    <li>

        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($page->ID); ?> "><?php echo $page->post_title ?></a>
        <?php
        if ( ($page->ID == $post->ID) || ($post->post_parent == $page->ID) ):   

        ?>
        <ul>
            <?php
                foreach($subpages as $subpage):
            ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($subpage->ID); ?> "><?php echo $subpage->post_title ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>

<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

Thanks